# Perform callbacks in a vector with Rust

Tags: rust, vector, callback, box, refcell

I've got an object with a bunch of registered handlers for callback events.

The type is defined as ..

```
    pub enum ObjectCatalog {
        String(String),
        Callback(Box<dyn FnMut()>),
        Mcu(mcu::MCU),
    }
    pub type VectorOfObjectCatalog = Rc<RefCell<Vec<ObjectCatalog>>>;
```

In the object, there is a variable of type (below) with a vector of objects that want to know about event X.

```
event_handlers: HashMap<&'a str, shared_types::VectorOfObjectCatalog>,
```

In my function that sends out events, it looks like this ...

```
pub fn send_event(&self, event: &'a str) {
            let set = self.event_handlers.get(event);
            match set {
                Some(vec) => {
                    for e in vec.borrow().iter() {
                        match e {
                            shared_types::ObjectCatalog::Callback(callback) => {
                                (callback)();
                            }
                            _ => {}
                        }
                    }
                }
                None => {}
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the error

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*callback` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
   --> src/main.rs:106:33
    |
106 | ...                   (callback)();
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ `callback` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

Why? I've seen examples where this works and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Calling an `f: FnMut()` requires that `f` be mutable. In your example, `callback` is immutable. You can instead use `Fn()` if it fits your use case

Comment: Or `vec.borrow_mut().iter_mut()`

Comment: nit: parentheses around `callback` are only needed when it's a field of a struct, `callback()` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, thanks, forgot about iter_mut().... needed a few more changes though, and they are here.

```
pub fn send_event(&self, event: &'a str) {
            let set = self.event_handlers.get(event);
            match set {
                Some(vec) => {
                    for mut e in vec.borrow_mut().iter_mut() {
                        match e {
                            shared_types::ObjectCatalog::Callback(callback) => {
                                (callback)();
                            }
                            _ => {}
                        }
                    }
                }
                None => {}
            }
        }
```